# TimeStamp variable stopped working in bash script with avconv

Tags: bash, raspbian, drawtext, avconv

The following script was working fine until I upgraded all my Raspberry Pis to Release 9:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/Videos/SecurityCam/
DToday=`date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'`
fn="VID $DToday"
SubT="PP $PB $DToday"

avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -t 3600 -r 4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \text=\'$SubT \%T \' : fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k \-y ${fn}.avi
```

It is now choking on the %T.  Why would that be and what is the right way to get a rolling timestamp in the video?

Comment: Are you sure you need the backslash before the percent sign in `\%T`?

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21905/how-to-set-pts-time-format-when-using-ffmpeg-filter-to-add-timestamp

Comment: @Leon Have tried it with and without the \

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Videos/SecurityCam/ || exit
DToday=$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
fn="VID $DToday"
SubT="PP $PB $DToday"

avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -t 3600 -r 4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \text=\'$SubT \%T \' : fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460"
 -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k -y "${fn}.avi"
```

Comment: This doesn't work!  And how is it different on the Timestamp issue than what I have shown?  The \%T still doesn't work, so changing how the filename is specified doesn't make sense to me.